Power Automate action "CreateNewDocumentSet" not working on specific date field
Stage:

SharePoint online document library "Contracts" with ~30 different fields, including 5 date-time fields. One of five is "Control Date" - our suspect.
Power Automate flow that creates document sets in this library. Flow is simple - trigger, action "CreateNewDocumentSet" and response.

Problem : action "CreateNewDocumentSet" cannot set date-time value in one particular field "Control Date", but has no issues setting value in other date-time fields.
Comments :

all 5 date-time fields are technically identical (example screenshot with suspect "Control Date" field - also empty formatting and validation)

I noticed problem during testing - initial flow was setting ~30 different field values, including 5 date-time field values.. but it did not saved value for field "Control Date"
different variations of flow action have been tested - setting all field values.. setting only date-time field values.. setting only "Control Date" field value.. setting different only date-time field values in different regional format. Every time same output - empty "Control Date"
all flow executions went without errors - actions succeeds and flow ends with green status "Your flow ran successfully". Also no errors in flow-runs.

Images below (with cleared personal data) represents flow action "CreateNewDocumentSet" input and output - as it is seen, date-time value is visible in "inputs", but missing in "outputs". Screenshots display variation where only field "Control Date" is set.


Goal : understand why one date-time field is no set and apply fix.
Update:

created new date-time column with same settings and added to flow. Flow ran without errors, successfully set value in other fields and in new field, but "Control Date" field still empty.


Found the issue : typo in field definition. :)
All fields were provisioned via PnP Provisioning scheme. Unfortunately, this field had a typo in StaticName - so it did not matched the Name (as per convention they should). As it turns out, such field is valid from SharePoint perspective, but not processed correctly by Power Automate internal actions.
<Field ID="{[guid]}" Name="KV_ControlDate" StaticName="KV_ControlnDate"...
                                                                 ^
                                                            -----^-----

